# How to retain item version when setting metadata

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm using the FrontPage RPC to upload documents to a document library.  Apparently there is a known issue/bug whereby the newer Office files (DOCX, XLSX, etc) will ignore the meta data info you set, so you end up having to call the setDocsMetaInfo to set the metadata after the fact.

The big problem with this is that it seems to up the version number of the item, which I don't want to happen.

Any help on how to set metadata on an existing item (whether by FrontPage RPC or SharePoint Web Service, it can't be the Client Object model), would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this situations, whatever call you perform post upload will most likely update version too. Of course the Lists.asmx would allow update of any fields (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx).

I would go for a Event receiver on the Item Update which should allow you total control over version and which metadata, by using SystemUpdate, find explanation (http://blog.amtopm.be/2011/09/06/update-vs-systemupdate-vs-updateoverwriteversion/)